# CSS3 circle with hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem creating this effect with CSS3. I know it's possible, but i can't figure out how to do it. We created it with Javascript (https://vimeo.com/104875594). Is there anyone of you who can help with this?

The problem is that the rotation animation will run backwards when you go from left to right in the circle, because your primary position is in the top. We need it to go 360 degrees around, and not only 180 degree.

Thanks.

You can see the code here: http://codepen.io/Seierup/pen/laEiB

```
<div class="about">
    <div class="about-circle">
        <div class="box-container">
            <div class="box">
            </div>
            <div class="box">
            </div>
            <div class="box">
            </div>
            <div class="box">
            </div>
            <div id="indicator-wrapper">
                <div class="arrow-Wrapper"></div>
                <div id="logo">R</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.about .about-circle .box-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 680px;
  background: #F7F7F7;
  position: relative;
}
.about .about-circle .box-container .box {
  padding-top: 20px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  text-align: center;
}
.about .about-circle #indicator-wrapper {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
}
.about .about-circle #indicator-wrapper .arrow-Wrapper {
  width: 166px;
  height: 166px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: -10px;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}
.about .about-circle #indicator-wrapper .arrow-Wrapper:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 20px solid #333;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  top: 12px;
  left: -4px;
  transform: rotateZ(-46deg);
}
.about .about-circle #indicator-wrapper .arrow-Wrapper:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: #333;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 200px;
}
.about .about-circle #logo {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background: #ffffff;
  z-index: 111;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  left: 12px;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 5em;
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 120px;
}
.about .about-circle .box-container .box:nth-of-type(1):hover ~ #indicator-wrapper .arrow-Wrapper {
  transform: rotateZ(0deg);
}
.about .about-circle .box-container .box:nth-of-type(2):hover ~ #indicator-wrapper .arrow-Wrapper {
  transform: rotateZ(90deg);
}
.about .about-circle .box-container .box:nth-of-type(3):hover ~ #indicator-wrapper .arrow-Wrapper {
  transform: rotateZ(-90deg);
}
.about .about-circle .box-container .box:nth-of-type(4):hover ~ #indicator-wrapper .arrow-Wrapper {
  transform: rotateZ(180deg);
}
```

Comment: You can use a rotation value which is more than 360° (or less than 0°). It may be easier to explain if you provide the piece of code that updates the element style.

Comment: I took your code, that was more simpler than mine and edited a bit! It does the exact same! Please look at problem :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see that you are new here so please in the future provide some code and jsfiddle we are here to help you not to do the work for you .

Using Pure CSS you can do this in [fullscreen](http://jsfiddle.net/kougiland/z7xywz56/3/embedded/result/)

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kougiland/z7xywz56/3/)

STYLE:

```
*{box-sizing:border-box; padding:0; margin:0;}

[id=overview]{
    width:650px;
    height:480px;
    background: #F7F7F7;
    position:relative;
}
[id=overview] img{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    position:relative;
    background:#333;
}
[id=overview] figcaption{
    color: #B6B6B6;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
[id=overview] figure{
    padding-top:20px;
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid #333;
    text-align:center;
}
[id=indicator-wrapper]{
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    border-radius:50%;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
}

[class=arrow-Wrapper]{
    width: 166px;
    height: 166px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    background: #ccc;
    margin:-10px;
    transition: all 300ms ease;
}

[class=arrow-Wrapper]:before,[class=arrow-Wrapper]:after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
}
[class=arrow-Wrapper]:before{
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 20px solid #333;
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    top: 12px;
    left: -4px;
    transform: rotateZ(-46deg);
}
[class=arrow-Wrapper]:after{
    background: #333;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 200px;
}

[id=logo]{
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    z-index: 111;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 12px;
    left: 12px;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 5em;
    font-weight: bolder;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 120px;
}


[id=overview] figure:nth-of-type(1):hover ~ [id=indicator-wrapper] .arrow-Wrapper{
    transform: rotateZ(0deg);
}
[id=overview] figure:nth-of-type(2):hover ~ [id=indicator-wrapper] .arrow-Wrapper{
    transform: rotateZ(91deg);
}
[id=overview] figure:nth-of-type(3):hover ~ [id=indicator-wrapper] .arrow-Wrapper{
    transform: rotateZ(269deg);
}
[id=overview] figure:nth-of-type(4):hover ~ [id=indicator-wrapper] .arrow-Wrapper{
    transform: rotateZ(180deg);
}
```

MARKUP:

```
<section id=overview>
    <figure>
        <img/>
        <figcaption>
            Some Text
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img/>
        <figcaption>
            Some Text
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img/>
        <figcaption>
            Some Text
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img/>
        <figcaption>
            Some Text
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
    <div id=indicator-wrapper>
        <div class=arrow-Wrapper></div>
        <div id=logo>R</div>
    </div>
</section>
```

[image]

Comment: That is exackly my problem! I'm sorry about my code..

As you can see, the hover effect turn around, when you go from Top-left -> Bottom left..

Comment: If you could provide you own code it would be great.Or show what you ve tried sofar

Comment: It is not difficult to get the result we have here! The difficult part is that the transition turns 280degree when you go from Top-Left to Top-bottom (On your example)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is exactly what you are looking for but it can work as a good reference on how to rotate something 360 degrees around. You can use

transform: rotate(-1turn); //or positive numbers to turn clockwise

Here is the whole example.

http://demosthenes.info/blog/860/Animating-Elements-In-Arcs-Circles-and-Ellipses-With-CSS